# Django- Getting string value instead of integer even when integer value in passed through `raise exceptions.ParseError`

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, parse-error

I want 0 or 1 in status through `raise exceptions.ParseError({'data':{},'message':'Email address already exists',"status":0})` but I am getting a string value

**code**

```
`def validate_email(self, email):

        email = get_adapter().clean_email(email)
        if allauth_settings.UNIQUE_EMAIL:
            if email and email_address_exists(email):

                # raise serializers.ValidationError({'status':0,'message':'Email address already exists'})
                raise exceptions.ParseError({'data':{'user':'nil'},'message':'Email address already exists','status':0})
        return email
`
```

**output**

**{
    "data": {},
    "status": "0",
    "message": "Email address already exists"
}**

**output image link**
[status as string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvoNa.png)

Comment: convert it to int by int() function.

Comment: tried but got same result

Comment: show us the code that generates the output, it's not clear how your error reaches the "output". What do you mean by "output"?

Comment: Code added please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to display this message ?

If it is on the server side i dunno why it is not working but you can try use a variable status and cast it like that:

```
raise exceptions.ParseError({'data':{},'message':'Email address already exists',"status":int(status)})
```

Comment: Try to use true/false variable then

Comment: but i need integer